# React-Native TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useContext.user') FireBase

Tags: javascript, android, ios, firebase, react-native

For firebase auth operations, I set up the AuthProvider.js structure whose codes I shared and tried to use it in Router.js, but I am getting this error. how can i fix it?
I guess 'import React, {useState,useEffect, useContext} from 'react';' i am getting an error here

Error:TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useContext.user')

My Router:

```js
import { AuthContext } from './Pages/AuthProvider/AuthProvider';
const Router = () => {
    const [isFirstLaunch,setIsFirstLaunch] = useState(null);
    const {user, setUser} = useContext(AuthContext);

    const {initializing,setInitializing} = useState(true);

    useEffect(()=>{
      AsyncStorage.getItem('alreadyLaunched').then(value=>{
        if(value== null){
          AsyncStorage.setItem('alreadyLaunched','true');
          setIsFirstLaunch(true);
        }else{
          setIsFirstLaunch(false);
        }
      });
    },[])
    if(isFirstLaunch == null){
      return null;
    }
    else if(isFirstLaunch== true){
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator 
            screenOptions={{
              headerShown:false
            }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen name='OnBoarding' component={OnBoardingPage}/>
            <Stack.Screen name='AuthStack' component={AuthStack}/>
            <Stack.Screen name='HomeStack' component={HomeStack}/>
            <FlashMessage position="top" />
          </Stack.Navigator>  
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
    else{
      return(
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator 
              screenOptions={{
                headerShown:false
              }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen name='AuthStack' component={AuthStack}/>
            <Stack.Screen name='HomeStack' component={HomeStack}/> 
          </Stack.Navigator>
          <FlashMessage position="top" />
        </NavigationContainer>
      )
    }
  }
```

My AuthProvider.js

```js
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';


export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        login: async (email, password) => {
          try {
            await auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        },
        register: async (email, password) => {
          try {
            await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        },
        logout: async () => {
          try {
            await auth().signOut();
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        },
      }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we should use this type:

```js
<AuthProvider>
  <Router/>
</AuthProvider>
```